# How to pull from gerrit after review in clean way

Tags: git, gerrit

We have gerrit (served on server, and path to repo is /a_repo, thus `git remote -v` returns `origin ssh://user@server:PORT/a_repo`) based workflow, which is - anyone working on project after

- cloning `git clone ssh://user@server/a_repo`, and
- checking out branch `git checkout fancy/named/branch`

is required to

- modify&commit changes `git commit -a -m "COMMIT_MSG"`
- push changes to review with `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/fancy/named/branch` (since I want to have it reviewed, in case I didn't I would push to **HEAD:refs/heads/fancy/named/branch** or **HEAD:refs/fancy/named/branch**?)

so far so good. Yet, after review is approved in gerrit,

- fetching `git fetch -a` says that origin/fancy/named/branch and fancy/named/branch has diverged commits.

One solution to this problem is to temporary switch to another branch, remove old with `git -D fancy/named/branch` and do `git co fancy/named/branch` again...which would create new branch based from those from origin. yet I find this cumbersome and against my view of git workflow.

Other solution is to rebase 'fancy/named/branch' on 'origin/fancy/named/branch' (`git co fancy/named/branch && git rebase origin/fancy/named/branch`)? 
This works too yet I'm not convinced is it totally safe.

I've been trying to grasp ways of gerrit with help of [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Gerrit_Code_Review) and `gerrit_server/gerrit/Documentation` but seem to fail to understand it as well as 'normal' git based operation and workflow.

How should I improve this? Should I even worry?

EDIT.

Actually given some thought about it it's silly question to ask. But I'm not deleting it if anyone else has similar doubts. Why it's silly?

Actually process is not so different from normal git workflow, after a commit and issuing a push - normally You'd need to do rebase or merge (in case someone pushed to this branch beside You).

Still, not to waste this question totally - perhaps someone could clarify difference between

- `git push HEAD:refs/heads/fancy/name/branch` and
- `git push HEAD:refs/fancy/named/branch`

in terms of gerrit related workflow? (while simple "for" in `refs/for/branch` will cause commit to undergo review process, how about two examples above?)

Comment: Why can't you just create a new "Remote" for gerrit? You can simply add a new remote by using "git remote add gerrit ssh://server/a_repo" So, instead of pushing to origin, you can push to that remote and fetch it once approved. Please try this, if happy will add my answer.